# Kafka Sink Connector - Custom Transformer: Connect to Azure Key Vault

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-keyvault

I have this connector that takes the information to a non-relational Database. What I want is that before I reach said component (DB) I want to perform certain transformations and for that I need to connect to the Azure KeyVault (personal purpose)

I have tried to do it programmatically, however, it gives me the following error:

```
DEBUG Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:39)
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
Invalid value class class com.package.kafka.connect.smt.MyTransformerTest$Value for configuration transforms.testtransformer.type: Error getting config definition from Transformation: Could not instantiate class com.package.MyTransformerTest
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.maybeAddConfigErrors(AbstractHerder.java:698)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$null$8(DistributedHerder.java:878)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.tick(DistributedHerder.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:326)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I identified that the error is due to the classes involved with the connection to AKV, which seems strange to me since I do not invoke them in the `apply()` method, which is where everything begins as I understand it. When I remove these classes and do the deployment, everything works correctly.

Do you know if there is a way to connect to AKV through the Connector configuration file and programmatically have an instance of the connection or something similar to be able to use it? Either to encrypt or decrypt information.

Comment: You can use a ConfigProvider, not a transform https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-config-provider-azure/index.html